# How to read a 32-bit integer image using matplotlib?

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, tiff

I need to read a **single-channel 32-bit integer TIFF image** from disk using Python 2 to perform some image analysis. I tried [`image.imread`](http://matplotlib.org/api/image_api.html?highlight=imread#matplotlib.image.imread) from matplotlib but I was unable to get the code to work because data were read as 4-channel 8-bit integer image:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import matplotlib.image as mpimg
>>> img = mpimg.imread('my_image.tif')
>>> img.shape
(52, 80, 4)
>>> img[0:2, 0:2]
array([[[255, 255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255, 255]],

       [[255, 255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255, 255]]], dtype=uint8)
```

**QUESTION**: Is it possible to read a single-channel 32-bit integer image using matplotlib?

I'm aware there are alternative ways to read such an image in Python, for example using [`Image.open`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.open) from PIL:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> img = np.asarray(Image.open('my_image.tif'))
>>> img.dtype
dtype('int32')
>>> img.shape
(52, 80)
>>> img[0:2, 0:2]
array([[8745, 8917],
       [8918, 9479]])
```

Another possibility would be using [`io.imread`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imread) from scikit-learn:

```
>>> from skimage import io
>>> img = io.imread('my_image.tif')
```

Yet another approach is to utilize the [`imread`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html?highlight=imread#cv2.imread) function from OpenCV. But in this case data have to be casted to 32-bit integer:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> img = cv2.imread('my_image.tif', -1)
>>> img[0:2, 0:2]
array([[  1.22543551e-41,   1.24953784e-41],
       [  1.24967797e-41,   1.32829081e-41]], dtype=float32)
>>> img.dtype = np.int32
>>> img[0:2, 0:2]
array([[8745, 8917],
       [8918, 9479]])
```

Comment: One more alternative is the [tifffile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tifffile) package.

Comment: Matplotlib is mainly intended for data visualization, not for data generation. `imread` is a convenience function which has its limitations. Since there are a lot of specialized image manipulation tools available, there is no need for such special case handling in matplotlib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html), there's no way to read a 32-bit integer image using matplotlib:

> Matplotlib plotting can handle float32 and uint8, but image reading/writing for any format other than PNG is limited to uint8 data.

For reference, I found out one more workaround based on [`ndimage.imread`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.imread.html) from SciPy:

```
from scipy import ndimage
img = ndimage.imread('my_image.tif', mode='I')
```

The approach based on [tifffile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tifffile) (suggested by @Warren Weckesser) also works fine:

```
from tifffile import TiffFile

with TiffFile('my_image.tif') as tif:
    img = tif.asarray()
```

Answer (score 1):

[SciPy no longer supports `imread` (versions 1.3.0+)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.1.3.0.html)

Instead you could use [imageio](https://pypi.org/project/imageio/) for scientific images:

```
import imageio

im = imageio.imread('imageio:astronaut.png') 

im.shape  # im is a numpy array
```